# C# Thread Programming

Tags: c#, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thread vs ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool)

What are the benefits of using ThreadPool instead of creating our own?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool

Comment: Do you mean Thread vs. ThreadPool ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool )?

Answer (score 1):

The main one is that it has already been thoroughly debugged and tested.

You can write your own and provide other functionality I suppose, but you really have to know what you are doing.  I've seen people do it, but it in my opinion, there isn't much of a benefit for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadPool` is already done, debugged, and lets you concentrate on writing code that you need to write instead of reinventing systems code that someone else has already written?