# Can I immediately stop a thread from running .NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, abort

I have the following code running in a thread to enumerate the local machines in the active directory. This takes some time to complete (about 5-10 seconds) so if the user quits the application before the enum is complete the application takes 5-10 seconds to quit. I tried thread.abort but because it is waiting for `For Each SubChildEntry In SubParentEntry.Children` to complete it doesn't abort until this returns.

```
    Dim childEntry As DirectoryEntry = Nothing
    Dim ParentEntry As New DirectoryEntry

        ParentEntry.Path = "WinNT:"
        For Each childEntry In ParentEntry.Children
            Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
            Select Case childEntry.SchemaClassName
                Case "Domain"
                    Dim SubChildEntry As DirectoryEntry
                    Dim SubParentEntry As New DirectoryEntry
                    SubParentEntry.Path = "WinNT://" & childEntry.Name

                    'The following line takes a long time to complete
                    'the thread will not abort until this returns
                    For Each SubChildEntry In SubParentEntry.Children 
                        Select Case SubChildEntry.SchemaClassName
                            Case "Computer"
                                _collServers.Add(SubChildEntry.Name.ToUpper)

                        End Select
                    Next

            End Select
        Next

        RaiseEvent EnumComplete()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to create and start up a new thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a BackgroundWorker thread, it supports canceling, see this answer

[C# Communication between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626390/c-communication-between-threads/2644229#2644229)

Comment: I have changed the code to use a background worker - this is now working as intended - thanks

Answer (score 2):

The idea might be to manage a `CancelPending` property that can be safely set and checked to see whether execution should proceed, or not:

```
For Each j In k

    If (CancelPending) Then
        Exit For
    End If

    ...

    Select ...
        Case "a"
            ...
            For Each x In y
                If (CancelPending) Then
                    Exit For
                End If

                ...
            Next
    End Select
Next
```

You can set `CancelPending` to true as part of your cancellation logic and expect the process to halt sooner.

Comment: I had this idea but it is the `For Each x In y` line that is taking the time to respond so the `If (CancelPending) Then` doesn't execute until it has finished