# Basic multi-threading questions in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, worker-thread

I'm new to multithreading and I'm working on parallelizing an area in my application. I've read a number of posts on this site but I'm still confused as to the best way to approach my problem:

[1] In .NET 3.5, is `ThreadPool` the only way for a program to exploit the multi-cores in the machine ? i.e. Is it possible to spawn threads on different cores using `new Thread()` ?

[2] My case: I have `List<Calculation>`that contains around 80 items, currently processed sequentially. So given that I'm using .NET 3.5 and based on what I've read, `ThreadPool` is probably my best bet for multithreading due to the high number of threads, however:

- There is a lot of dependency between the Calculations. Currently, the list is ordered in a way that all required Calculations are performed in the beginning.

This is how the dependency of the work items looks like (details not important, just wanted to make a point on the complexity of the dependencies):

[image]

- Calculation times are vastly different, one Calculation object might just involve retrieval of a value , other Calculation objects would involve a lot of work in nested loops...etc

How do I prioritize the main `Calculations` that have something like 10+ other work items depending on it ? What is the most efficient way of signaling to use ?

Thank you.

Edit: I should mention that `List<Calculation>` remains fixed. However, computing the 80+ calculations is called x million times. Every time an iterator is updated, Calculate() is invoked on every `Calculation` in the list.

Comment: I don't suppose there's any chance you could upgrade to .NET 4.0? PLINQ is awesome for stuff like this.

Comment: Your image is too small to be readable!

Comment: @Michael: I did that on purpose. I was just trying to make a point on the complexity of the dependencies. You can give the drawings your own labels !

Comment: Why do you have to be able to read the text in the image to answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] In .NET 3.5, is ThreadPool the only way for a program to exploit the multi-cores in the machine ? i.e. Is it possible to spawn threads on different cores using new Thread() ?

It's up to the operating system to decide which core a thread should run on. The OS will per default distribute threads evenly over multiple cores (at least in windows).

`ThreadPool` are using the same kind of threads as the `Thread` class, as there really are only one kind (but different types of classes and algorithms wrapping them)

> [2] My case: I have Listthat contains around 80 items, currently processed sequentially. So given that I'm using .NET 3.5 and based on what I've read, ThreadPool is probably my best bet for multithreading due to the high number of threads, however:

Using `ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem` seems to be the easiest way for you to convert your application.

Keep in mind that running 100 different threads doesn't say that your application will be 10 times faster than running 10 threads. It's more likely that 10 threads will run faster sine a lot if background stuff happens when .net and the OS switches between threads.

1. I would convert the `List` into a `Queue`
2. When launching your calculations, add 10 (or any number you like) calls to ThreadPool.QueueWorkerItem(MyMethod);
3. In MyMethod, create a loop that continue to dequeue items from your queue until there are no more jobs left.

Answer (score 2):

[1]: Yes, it is possible to spawn threads on different cores using `new Thread()`, although you might be better served using the threadpool. The differences are discussed here:

[Thread vs ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool)

Comment: Thanks. The link to the blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/08/05/dedicated-thread-or-a-threadpool-thread.aspx) says a dedicated thread would be better than using ThreadPool when it is required to have a thread with a particular priority

Answer (score 2):

This would be SO MUCH EASIER in .Net 4.0 using [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx).

When are you scheduled to upgrade?  It might be sooner than you could write all the required coordinating code yourself.

If you do have to do this brute force, you can use [Thread.BeginThreadAffinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx) to ensure enclosed code runs on a single CPU.  This should help your calculation performance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx#S1) makes this very easy.

```
List<Calculation> foo = ...;
foo.AsParallel.Select(c => c.Calculate());
```

Comment: But that assumes that there are no dependencies between the Calculation objects ?

Comment: This uses .Net 4 if I am not mistaken

Comment: @steve townsend, yes it does depend on the 4.0 release of the framework... if that is a problem you'd have to manage your own threads as other posts note.

Comment: @alhazen, you haven't really specified how the dependencies are defined or managed.  If each calculation links to other calculation objects... it seems like it would make sense to do some kind of on demand execution and storage of the result within a calculation object... so if an object has a dependency to a calculation that hasn't executed in the list yet, that happens when its requested.