# How can i run mouse_move event in a thread...?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

My application plot values from an electronic device. It plots 10 values in one second. It waits for 100ms before fetching the next value. The waiting is given by `Thread.Sleep(100);` This much part is working fine.

I am showing the mouse position in MouseMove event. But to show the position it takes a delay which i have given before.

So i want to avoid that delay. I tried to run the MouseMove event in thread like `new Thread(chartControl1_MouseMove).Start();`. But it gives the following errors:

> 1. The best overloaded method match for
>      'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart)' has some invalid arguments.
> 2. Argument '1': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'

Any suggestions...???

Comment: What do you mean by "I am showing the mouse position" ? Does this mean you are fetching the mouse position and plotting this into your chart?

Comment: Similar question, same error (see comments), same solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155979/c-thread-method

Answer (score 0):

MouseMove event takes some arguments. But the thread start isnt passing them. its assuming that the method has void params.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your method `chartControl1_MouseMove` which I take is declared as

```
public void chartControl1_MouseMove(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
```

can not be converted to to a `ThreadStart` delegate which takes the form of

```
public delegate void ThreadStart()
```

to make this work you will need to create a method of its own with void return type and no parameters like

```
private void foo()
```

and change your line of code to:

```
new Thread(foo).Start();
```

That way it should at least compile. You then have to implement the desired behaviour inside the `foo` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a method that requires parameters. Either change the method to have no parameters, or use a worker item:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Method(m));
```

You need to convert your method `chartControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` to something that contains one argument, or you can revert to using Tasks instead. In general, it's often better to place your working code in its own method and let the event be the event (which is already called asynchronously if in a form). Then you call the working method (queue it) from the event.

There are advantages of using a thread pool over threads, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool).

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterizedThreadStart or better move the body of mouse_move handler to some other method and run that method on thread.