# Thread is not working

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Can someone tell me why the below code is not working?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(rtb2);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void rtb2()
    {
        try
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "1";                
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("HI");
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "not working", but I'd bet it was because you're not using `Control.Invoke` to update the UI.

Comment: JaredParand ChristF are both right ... but you really should have been clearer about "Not working" ;)

Comment: FWIW, for short lived threads, use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem over spawning a new thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool

Comment: Since you knew that an exception was being thrown you could have figured out the problem from the exception itself: MessageBox.Show("HI "+ex.ToString());

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your attempting to modify a Winforms UI element from a background thread.  This is specifically not allowed by the WinForms model.  UI elements can only be modified from the main thread.  You need to use `Control.Invoke` in order to get the context back onto the appropriate thread.

```
private void rtb2() {
  Action action = delegate {
    richTextBox1.Text = "1";
  };

  try {
    this.Invoke(action);
  } catch(InvalidOperationException ex) {
     MessageBox.Show("HI");
  }
}
```