# Disadvantages of using ThreadPool for long running threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I am using the thread pool within my Windows service for doing parallel processing. My threads are long ones. What are the negative points in my design?

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer here - [Is it true that for long running processes it is better to do thread manually instead of threadpool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298641/is-it-true-that-for-long-running-processes-it-is-better-to-do-thread-manually-in)

> That is true. The thread pool is optimised for small units of work and
>   you can interfere with other work by holding onto a thread pool
>   thread.
>
> My rule of thumb is if an operation can take more than a second, it
>   should not be on a thread pool thread. That is probably quite long.
>
> Although this is undocumented, if you start a Task with
>   TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning then a new Thread will be started to
>   run the Task.
>
> For most IO tasks, there are asynchronous versions of the framework
>   methods that you should really use. These make use of kernel functions
>   and mean that you won't be blocking any thread.
>
> As always, I recommend reading Joe Albahari's free ebook, followed by
>   Joe Duffy's Concurrent Programming on Windows. The later is 1000 pages
>   long, but is full of useful details.

Answer (score 0):

Although using threads gives the appearance of being able to do more, each thread takes up part of your CPU, and a little bit more memory.  If you have a thread for a long running task it has the potential for the threadpool to hault that thread for a short time in order give room for other tasks \ threads.

You would be better to split that thread into smaller tasks using async tasks and have them wait, waitall and some other options.

This link here should help you a little bit further

[Tasks, Await, Await All...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)