# .NET/C# - Efficient way to perform repetitive parallel tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I need to perform two parallel tasks multiple times in a .NET 3.5/C#/WPF program.

In my case, the tasks perform some calculation on data provided by a device (Kinect). So each time new data are received I need to start two tasks doing different computation.
I am using `Thread` for each task and when I receive new data I recreate each thread with a `new` statement.

```
// Data received
task1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExtractData1));
task2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExtractData2));
```

Everything is working correctly, but my question is about efficiency.
I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this...

Should I keep using `Thread` like this ?
Is there a performance hit to recreate the `Thread` each time ?
Should I create the `Thread` only once and use `ManualResetEvent` to trigger the computation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a version of Microsofts Reactive Extensions, which claim to 'bridge' some functions of the 4.0 TPL. Maybe it's interesting for you: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24940

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
I am thinking to switch to .NET 4/4.5 now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting a new Thread does carry some additional overhead, one possible alternative is to make use of the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.ThreadPool%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(o => ExtractData1()));
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(o => ExtractData2()));
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230023/921321) is a comparison of starting a new Thread vs using the ThreadPool. The real summary is that a thread is usually more performant for longer running tasks (something which may take more than a second or two) whereas the ThreadPool is able to recycle existing threads, which alleviates a lot of the initial overhead.

Comment: On .NET 4.0+ check the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) class.  It uses `ThreadPool` to manage work behind the scenes and provides an easier to use API.

Comment: The asker is using .NET 3.5 which is pre-TPL, but yes, the TPL does alleviate a lot of these problems if it is available.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with `ThreadPool`... I can also switch to .NET 4 or 4.5, in that case should I use `Task` ? (Should I edit my question to add a .NET 4/4.5 part ?)

Comment: @Nems I'm glad the answer helped, be sure to mark as answer once you are able :)

Comment: @Nems - If you are switching to .Net 4.0 or higher, `TPL` is a way to go for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of each thread causes about 1MB of memory to be allocated for its stack. That's expensive.

Unless your calculation is processor intensive then don't bother with threads.

Your best bet is to benchmark all three of the options.