# Best thread practices to apply in C# for lazily-unloading multiple AppDomains created dynamically

Tags: c#, multithreading, background, task, lazy-evaluation

Consider having an application which creates 30 app-domains, then runs them (each app-domain in its own thread) and when each of these app-domains finishes running (aka its thread exits and so on) we need to cleanup by running for each appdomain some custom cleanup-logic + a call for unloading the appdomain itself.

The cleanup logic + appdomain-unloading call for each of these app-domains might require *more than one attempts to succeed* (due to resources being involved, taking time to be released by the system and so on). If the cleanup operation cannot be performed in a specific attempt, it doesn't take more than 100ms for us to know about this and move on.

What is the best practice, in the world of C#, to perform such cleanup in a 'perform-cleanup-in-the-background' fashion? Possible venues off the top of my head:

1. Each app-domain cleanup should be performed in its very own 'new Thread()' corner. Each thread persists in a while loop with a sleep interval in case it needs to retry.
2. Have just a single, dedicated long-running thread with a task-queue in which we submit each and every appdomain to be cleaned-up and unloaded (again in a persistent fashion like in method #1 above).
3. Using a thread-pool and submitting the cleanup-tasks there

According to the following comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28651533/863651

"If a method cannot be expected to exit within 100ms or so of when it starts execution, the method should be executed via some means other than the main thread pool.[ ... ] If, however, a method will take a second or longer to execute, and will spend most of its time blocked, the method should likely be run in a dedicated thread, and should almost certainly not be run in a main-threadpool thread."

I guess this discourages using method #3 above. I'm wondering if method#2 has any considerable advantages over method #1. The main thing that bugs me is that even though method#2 needs slightly more coding it uses just 1 thread no matter what, while method#2 will require N threads for N app-domains (with all the cost that this entails in terms of spawning the threads etc).

I'm open to suggestions about any method#4+ that there might be to implement such mechanism. I'm just curious to see how other programmers apply the concept of "best threading-practices" when it comes to such a problem.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: This application is meant to be run in contemporary desktop computers (at the time of this writing).

Comment: What cleanup operations need to be performed, and what determines when a given AppDomain needs to spin down?

Comment: Cleanup operations: Writing to a database (SQLite if it makes any difference) + deleting temporary files are just 2 standard tasks. An AppDomain enters the 'spin down' phase (aka becomes garbage-collection-worthy if I understand the wording correctly) when it has completed a series of tasks coded into it (displaying some c# dialogs, running dos commands, launching apps etc). These tasks are not fixed and vary from one appdomain to the next (the appdomains are generated dynamically). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you know what will need to be cleaned up at some point when you're managing the AppDomains, you can attach cleanup logic to the DomainUnload event like:

```
appDomain.DomainUnload += 
  (sender, args) => 
  {
       //this logic needs to be specific for each AppDomain.

       //you can consider using a class like BackgroundWorker to do the work.

  };
```

For the single vs. multi-thread question, as long as you make your code thread safe, then my take is that the multi-threaded option would both reduce the lines of code (always a goal of mine) and optimize performance, especially if running cleanup as a background thread. 10s of threads is really a non-issue as far as tapping out system resources (unless cleanup operations may exhaust memory). The main drawback is that multi-threaded programs can sometimes be trickier to debug, but I bet you'll be okay in this case.

Comment: +1 for the DomainUnload bit. I'm still in limbo on whether the reduction in code-size justifies invoking 30 threads vS raising one thread but making the code more complex (usage of a queue, maintenance etc).

Comment: As long as you make the code thread safe, then my take is that you both reduce the lines of code (always a goal of mine) and optimize performance, especially if running cleanup as a background thread. 10s of threads is really a non-issue as far as tapping out system resources (unless cleanup operations may exhaust memory). The main drawback is that multi-threaded programs can sometimes be trickier to debug, but I bet you'll be okay in this case.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to copy-paste your comment into an answer-candidate? Just for the sake of keeping inline with the format of the site.