# what are alternatives of Threadpool ?

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have this piece of code:

```
 public void GenerateImageAsync(Area area)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(threading  =>
        {
            ready.Reset();
            GenerateImage(area);
            ready.Set();
        });
    }
```

can you tell me how can i change it, or use alternative of Threadpool?

Comment: Why do you need to change it - what is the problem?

Comment: yes i want to change it. i want to use something different instead of Threadpool

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `ThreadPool`? What's wrong with that?

Comment: Like `Task.Run`? What are you trying to accomplish by not using ThreadPool? Under the hood `Task.Run` still uses the ThreadPool, so we need to know what your actual end goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a Task, which will create a thread in the threadpool like this:

```
public void GenerateImageAsync(Area area)
    {
        Task.Run(() => {
            ready.Reset();
            GenerateImage(area);
            ready.Set();
        });
    }
```

or a actual Thread like this:

```
public void GenerateImageAsync(Area area)
    {
        new Thread(() => {
            ready.Reset();
            GenerateImage(area);
            ready.Set();
        }).Start();
    }
```

Comment: How is any of them a replacement to ThreadPool? there is difference between thread and threadpool .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool

Comment: @lazy What do you mean by *The thread is still not a managed thread?*

Comment: Well a new Thread is an alternative to Thread Pool, I added the Task because I was unsure if OP meant the ThreadPool class, or actual thread pools.

Comment: I was not sure about the question but the alternate is ambiguous too. There is difference between thread and threadpool. Sorry for using the word managed. You can read more about the difference in the link in my comment