# Listen(), Task.Run

Tags: c#, multithreading

Do I understand correctly that the code below each `HandleContextAsync(context))` runs in a new thread? Using the best way to limit the number of threads

```
private void Listen()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (listener.IsListening)
            {
                var context = listener.GetContext();
                sem.WaitOne();
                Task.Run(() => HandleContextAsync(context));
            }
            else
                Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }
}
private async Task HandleContextAsync(HttpListenerContext listenerContext)
{
    //I process the image received in the request
    var iBit = imageBit.Clone(imageInterSect, imageBit.PixelFormat);
    iBit.Save(listenerContext.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    listenerContext.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    listenerContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    listenerContext.Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: each HandleContextAsync(context)) *can* run in *another* thread. But more important, What does HandleContextAsync do? Does it return Task? then await that one. You are now creating a fire-and-forget task. You'll never know when it is ready and how it finished..

Comment: private async Task HandleContextAsync(HttpListenerContext listenerContext)
{ 
await new Task(() => { //query context processing});
}

Comment: So, you do a Task.Run twice? That's not a good idea. Change `Task.Run(() => HandleContextAsync(context));`
 to `await HandleContextAsync(context)`. Please update the question to include (part of) the code of `HandleContextAsync`

Comment: @PeterBons Added description HandleContextAsync :)

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Run(()=>Action)` basically creates a task and task is allocated to some thread from thread pool. So yes, you are correct it runs in a different thread (but not newly created thread)

This is somewhat more flexible programming paradigm version of QueueUserWorkItem. The purpose is - optimize use of resources because thread creation and usage is considered to be costly affair and let runtime manage it in best possible way.

Comment: I think 'limit' is not right word here. But yes, I can say to 'optimize and better management of resource' is better to use thread pool. You can see detail explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool

Comment: My serer will be subject to a heavy load, and it makes no sense to limit the flows?

Comment: algorithm to create new thread in thread pool is already there in case current numbers of threads in pool doesn't suffice. And it does so based on certain pattern

Comment: The load exceeds the capabilities of the server and the server must work stably

Comment: if the load exceeds the capabilities you either need to scale up/out or offload the processing job to another process using a message queue for example.

Comment: @PeterBons I wanted to organize the stability of the server using semaphore or mutex