# Help with downloading with progressbar

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a simple downloader, but i cant make it to update the GUI elements in my Form (`Form1`).

In the constructor for Form1 i call thread:

```
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fetch));
        t.Start();
```

And fetch looks something like this:

```
private void fetch()
{
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
            webClient.DownloadFile(updateurl, @"foo.iso");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
}
```

None of the events are triggered... altho, by looking at the foo.iso in the folder i see the file increase in size.

One of the events looks like this:

```
void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{   
    progressBar.Value = (int)(e.BytesReceived * 100 / e.TotalBytesToReceive);

    statusLabel.Text = "Downloading";
    descLabel.Text = progressBar.Value + " % complete";
}
```

Comment: In general, don't explicitly start a thread, use a background thread from the thread pool.  Do this with QueueUserWorkItem or some other call that relies on the pool. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684640/advantage-of-using-thread-start-vs-queueuserworkitem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to perform your `fetch` method in another thread, just use [`DownloadFileAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync.aspx) instead of `DownloadFile` and it should work asynchronously.

Also, that's the reason why `DownloadProgressChanged` event doesn't trigger:

it works only with asynchronous calls [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, why they are not raised, but the problem is, that you are trying to update the UI from a non-UI thread.
How to do it, can be seen here: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: ive added the delegate, but it does still no trigger the event... i still see the foo.iso increase :(

Comment: @Jason94: the problem is that those events don't work with `DownloadFile` call. Look at my answer...

Comment: The answer to that question is in the answer of digEmAll