# C# How to kill a blocked thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, zip, gzip, block

I have a thread:

```
void threadCode(object o)
{
  doStuffHere(o); // Blocking call. Sometimes hangs.
}
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
  {
    threadCode(o);
  }));
t.Start();

StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
sw.Start();

while (t.IsAlive)
{
  Application.DoEvents();

  if (sw.EllapsedMilliseconds > myTimeout)
    // Somehow kill t even though doStuffHere(o) is blocked (but hung)
}
```

I'm using the [.NET Zip Library](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) and calling `ZipFile.CommitUpdate()` which works most of the time, but sometimes just hangs. I don't know why, I can't see anything in the documentation which specifies why this is happening. A small file which should take no longer than 5 - 10 seconds will sometimes sit there for more then 5 minutes with no progress. I/O graphs in process explorer show that the process is not reading or writing, and there is no CPU usage. Basically, if this happens, I want to kill `CommitUpdate()` and try again once or twice before giving up.

Any idea how I can kill a thread stuck in a blocking call?

(Alternatively - those of you with experience with this zip library: do you know why it might be hanging with some files sometimes? I'm modifying the contents of .docx and .pptx (GZip) files. This would be an ideal solution.)

Comment: Killing a thread is not a good idea as it doesn't release resources. I'd suggest using some maintained component for .NET which doesn't have such bugs and where you can get support.

Comment: Also, in general, don't start your own threads. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684640/advantage-of-using-thread-start-vs-queueuserworkitem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `Thread.Abort` to bloodily murder the thread.

The thread will not be able to clean up after itself (except for `finally` blocks); depending on exactly what it was doing at the time, it could seriously mess up your program.

Answer (score 9):

If you're going to terminate the hanging thread by using `Thread.Abort()`, make sure you handle `ThreadAbortException` in your thread code. The normal pattern is:

```
try {
    // do work here
}
catch (ThreadAbortException) {
    // allows your thread to gracefully terminate
    Thread.ResetAbort();
}
catch {
    // regular exception handling
}
```

If you don't follow the above pattern, then at best your threads will terminate ungracefully. At worst, you could run into a number of other problems.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to using a Stopwatch, you could do this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
{
   threadCode(o);
}));
thread.Start();

thread.Join(myTimeout);
if(thread.IsAlive)
{
   thread.Abort();
}
```

Comment: I didn't think it would be so simple. I'm going to give this a try now. I thought Thread.Abort() just sent a signal to the thread to abort, which would trigger an event handler in the Thread.

Comment: @Ozzah: No; that's the safe way to do it.  `Abort` is _dangerous_.

Comment: @SLaks although [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) says `Calling this method **usually** terminates the thread.` I wonder what that implies.

Comment: If the thread calls `ResetAbort` in a `catch` or `finally`, it won't terminate.

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT use Thread.Abort() to workaround a bug in a library you're using. (Or it could be a bug in your code).

Either get the original bug fixed, or move to a different library.

ps: You might want to try DotNetZip, in lieu of SharpZipLib.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Thread.Abort() method to kill a thread.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332365(VS.71).aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you could use [`Thread.Abort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) to terminate the thread - don't expect any orderly shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, so I not sure about this, but does `t.Abort();` do the trick?