# How to stop a thread running a blocking method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm making a server application and I'm using a thread running in a while(true) a blocking listening function.

How can I stop the thread?
I can't use this kind of code:

```
while(true)
{
    BlockingMethod();
    if(shouldStop)
        return;
}
```

Because it will be executed till BlockingMethod "unblocks"...

Comment: So you want to stop the thread even if it's busy doing something inside the BlockingMethod()?

Comment: Yes, because when the user stops the application (made with WPF), the process is still running...

Comment: @ApocKalipsS Have you set true to `thread.IsBackground`?

Comment: No, will it fix my problem with my process not stopping?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# How to kill a blocked thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560817/c-sharp-how-to-kill-a-blocked-thread)

Comment: @ApocKalipsS How hard would it be to test it?

Comment: Harder than answering Yes, but thanks, it worked!

Comment: @ApocKalipsS duration between your comments is 7 mins. So this shows, it is not much harder then answering.

Comment: Can you 'artificially' satisfy the blocking conditiion from another thread?  What does the blocking call do - what does it wait on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good practice, and you should avoid it if possible, but you can call the `Thread.Abort()` method if you have no way to stop the `BlockingMethod()`.

Info on it here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyayh29d(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyayh29d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I'd advise you to try to change your `BlockingMethod()` in a way you can pass a Cancellation Token and abort it in a graceful way.

As Yuval Itzchakov specified, "if he passes a `CancellationToken` he has to actively check on it from time to time. It wont work if the method blocks. If you choose to use `Thread.Abort()` make sure you catch (ThreadAbortException) and set `Thread.ResetAbort`" and "`Task.Run` with a cancellation token can take care of it, if the Task is cancelled prior to the blocking call" (Pete Garofano).

Comment: Even if he passes a `CancellationToken` he has to actively check on it from time to time. It wont work if the method blocks. If you choose to use `Thread.Abort()` make sure you `catch (ThreadAbortException)` and set `Thread.ResetAbort`

Comment: Task.Run with a cancellation token will handle it.

Comment: Only if the `Task` was cancelled prior to the blocking call

Comment: Expanded the answer with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Thread.Join(TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23f7b1ct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to give the thread a chance to end gracefully, followed by [Thread.Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx)