# What is the most efficient method for assigning threads based on the following scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, api

I can have a maximum of 5 threads running simultaneous at any one time which makes use of 5 separate hardware to speedup the computation of some complex calculations and return the result. The API (contains only one method) for each of this hardware is not thread safe and can only run on a single thread at any point in time. Once the computation is completed, the same thread can be re-used to start another computation on either the same or a different hardware depending on availability. Each computation is stand alone and does not depend on the results of the other computation. Hence, up to 5 threads may complete its execution in any order.

What is the most efficient C# (using .Net Framework 2.0) coding solution for keeping track of which hardware is free/available and assigning a thread to the appropriate hardware API for performing the computation? Note that other than the limitation of 5 concurrently running threads, I do not have any control over when or how the threads are fired.

Please correct me if I am wrong but a lock free solution is preferred as I believe it will result in increased efficiency and a more scalable solution.

Also note that this is not homework although it may sound like it...

Comment: What do you mean by 5 separate hardware? You want to distribute over 5 machines?

Comment: I am imagining that he has 5 things like co-processor devices on-board. Maybe they are special hardware encyption devices. Whatever - they do something computationally intensive, let's say. And they each can do only one thing at a time. They are not remote general purpose computers, so this is not a question of distributed computing. instead they are special-purpose resources, that are used by a single program.

Answer (score 2):

.NET provides a thread pool that you can use. `System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` tells a thread in the pool to do some work for you.

Were I designing this, I'd not focus on mapping threads to your HW resources. Instead I'd expose a lockable object for each HW resource - this can simply be an array or queue of 5 Objects.  Then for each bit of computation you have, call `QueueUserWorkItem()`.  Inside the method you pass to QUWI, find the next available lockable object and lock it (aka, dequeue it).  Use the HW resource, then re-enqueue the object, exit the QUWI method.

It won't matter how many times you call QUWI; there can be at most 5 locks held, each lock guards access to one instance of your special hardware device.

The [doc page for `Monitor.Enter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx) shows how to create a safe (blocking) Queue that can be accessed by multiple workers.  In .NET 4.0, you would use [the builtin BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) - it's the same thing.

That's basically what you want. Except don't call `Thread.Create()`.  Use the thread pool.

cite: [Advantage of using Thread.Start vs QueueUserWorkItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684640/advantage-of-using-thread-start-vs-queueuserworkitem)

---

```
// assume the SafeQueue class from the cited doc page. 
SafeQueue<SpecialHardware> q = new SafeQueue<SpecialHardware>()

// set up the queue with objects protecting the 5 magic stones
private void Setup() 
{
    for (int i=0; i< 5; i++) 
    {
       q.Enqueue(GetInstanceOfSpecialHardware(i));
    }
}


// something like this gets called many times, by QueueUserWorkItem()
public void DoWork(WorkDescription d)
{
    d.DoPrepWork();

    // gain access to one of the special hardware devices
    SpecialHardware shw = q.Dequeue();
    try 
    {
        shw.DoTheMagicThing();
    }
    finally 
    {
        // ensure no matter what happens the HW device is released
        q.Enqueue(shw);
        // at this point another worker can use it.
    }

    d.DoFollowupWork(); 
}
```

Comment: Using locks like that would block each thread that want to access the hardware until it can. Hence if 20 different threads want to access the same HW they will all block until they get access. My solution will take a job request and then let each calling thread continue on with other work. You also might want to elaborate on why using dedicated threads is a bad thing in this case, since five threads doesn't take much resources but makes the code easier to follow and debug.

Comment: `Using locks like that would block each thread that want to access the hardware until it can.`  I think that is the goal.  Allow only one thread to access each HW resource, at one time.

Comment: The point was rather `Hence if 20 different threads want to access the same HW they will all block until they get access`. By using dedicated threads that are avoided.

Comment: right: by using dedicated threads, you avoid the case where any of the N threads block waiting for access for the M resources.  But in that case you must explicitly manage a pool of **jobs**, which is more complex than my approach where you manage nothing.  I don't see the benefit in explicitly managing a pool of jobs, so that you can have exactly 5 thread working and no threads blocking. Who cares if threads block?  QUWI lets you just dump work into the thread pool, and forget about it. All you need is a concurrent queue.

Comment: The problem with using the thread pool to handle blocking operations is that it can cause thread pool starvation. Fire and forget approach is usually a lot better for jobs that can complete without having to wait on something.

Answer (score 1):

A lock free solution is only beneficial if the computation time is very small.

I would create a facade for each hardware thread where jobs are enqueued and a callback is invoked each time a job finishes.

Something like:

```
public class Job
{
    public string JobInfo {get;set;}
    public Action<Job> Callback {get;set;}
}

public class MyHardwareService
{
    Queue<Job> _jobs = new Queue<Job>();
    Thread _hardwareThread;
    ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public MyHardwareService()
    {
        _hardwareThread = new Thread(WorkerFunc);
    }

    public void Enqueue(Job job)
    {
      lock (_jobs)
        _jobs.Enqueue(job);

       _event.Set();
    }

    public void WorkerFunc()
    {
        while(true)
        {
             _event.Wait(Timeout.Infinite);
             Job currentJob;
             lock (_queue)
             {
                currentJob = jobs.Dequeue();
             }

             //invoke hardware here.

             //trigger callback in a Thread Pool thread to be able
             // to continue with the next job ASAP
             ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => job.Callback(job));

            if (_queue.Count == 0)
              _event.Reset();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Moved my answer to your question since it's more suited there.

Comment: using locks like ... *what*? Using QUWI is recommended unless you have a specific reason to manage your own threads. The reasons are well known and documented elsewhere. Basically: let .NET do it for you; your app probably doesn't know enough about the machine to handle thread scheduling and optimization well, and shouldn't be focused on that anyway.

Comment: No. Using the thread pool is not the recommended way if the threads will wait on something like hardware. You could cause a thread pool starvation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a thread pool with 5 threads where each one relinquishes the HW once it's done and adds it back to some queue. Would that work? If so, .Net makes thread pools very easy.

Comment: you don't need to create a pool containing 5 threads.  .NET has a thread pool, it has N threads, and you generally don't care how many there are. The important thing here is the 5 resources.  You need 5 lockable objects that guard the 5 resources.  Any thread in the pool can then lock the object, use the resource it guards, then release the object. Start as many background work tasks as you like, there will be at most 5 running concurrently.

Comment: I think this is a particular case where you _do_ care about the number of threads. Why would you create more than 5 if any additional thread will certainly block? What's gained?

Comment: there's no telling. It could be that there is some work that can be done by the thread before locking the HW resource. There could be some post-processing by the thread after the work on the HW resource is complete.  But there is virtually no cost to having additional threads waiting on the queue of resource locks. It's an easy abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like the [Sleeping barber problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem). I believe the standard solution to that is to use [semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)