# Cancel ThreadPool .QueueUserWorkItem Task

Tags: c#, threadpool, cancellation

I need to cancel a background task started using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...). I know a BackgroundWorker has constructs especially for this sort of thing, but I believe it's overkill in this case, since no user interface is involved. By cancellation, I simply mean force the completion of the callback method.

What are the pitfalls of adding something like the following to my class?

```
// Cancellation Property.
private bool _canceled;
public bool CancelTask
{
    get { return _canceled; }
    set { _canceled = value; }
}

public void DoSomeTask()
{
    int iterations = 50;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadPoolCallback), iterations);
}

private void ThreadPoolCallback(object state)
{
    if (_canceled)
        return; // don't even start.

    int iterations = (int)state;
    for (int i = 0; !_canceled && i < iterations; i++)
    {
        //
        // do work ...
        //

        // This allows you to cancel in the middle of an iteration...
        if (_canceled)
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I've used similar techniques many times without any problems; the only problem that I see is that if more than one thread might try to write to `_canceled`.  But for a simple "write once, read once, exit" kind of flag, I've never had a problem.  I'd be curious to hear other thoughts though.

Comment: Just make sure that _canceled is correctly synchronized.  I'd suggest using the interlocked functions to modify that variable so that there is a memory barrier.

Comment: You must either use *volatile* for the _canceled member declaration *or* use the CancelTask property getter.  Without this, there's a definite possibility that your worker method never sees the update.  BGW has very little overhead, favor code that's been tested by many thousands and maintained by somebody else.

Comment: Can you use .NET 4.0?  If you can, you can use the TPL.  It has great support for cancellation mechanisms.

Comment: @Bryan -- not yet, we're using .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a method CancelTask() rather than a property. The point is that callers should be able to cancel a task, but no one should be able to un-cancel a task.

Then you need to be sure that the read and the write of _cancelled have the appropriate memory barriers otherwise one thread might not ever observe the change made by the other thread. For this I'd use Thread.VolatileWrite (inside CancelTask) and Thread.VolatileRead (inside your loop)