# How can I make a loader animation that runs while code executes?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation, load, loading

I have a page that runs a large amount of code to prepare the page and layout of the page for the user.

It only needs to be used once in a blue moon. But when it does, it's about three seconds of wait for the user.

Apparently, Microsoft only allows a 2 or less second wait. Daaaaang.

I've optimized and optimized the code, and there's no way around it: the code is as fast as it can be. So naturally, I set out to make a loader.

I tried to update several controls, but thanks to the UI thread being frozen, they didn't work.

I searched and searched and searched, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806535/wpf-loading-animation-on-a-separate-ui-thread-c), which was confusing and didn't really help, partly because of WP7's version of C# and partly because of me being a beginner at C#.

How can I make a loader that works while the UI thread is frozen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Silverlight Toolkit For Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) introduces the `PerformanceProgressBar`, "which uses the compositor thread exclusively for animation, instead of the UI (user interface) thread" as [described in this WindowsPhone Geek article](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-PerformanceProgressBar-in-depth). This should help you with the freezing UI.

As of the parallel execution (suggested by Merlyn), I'd suggest the [QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method to execute code in a separate thread over the `BackgroundWorker`, leaving the UI thread active for UI updates, but as described in the article, you will need to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to update your UI from there.

Comment: Thanks! I finally have a progress bar, even if it does display a little slowly on the emulator and doesn't show how the % done. Also, I boosted your rep into the 4-digit zone!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [the `BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).  That page has a tutorial for how to use it.

See this question and my answer for another tutorial.  Though not Windows Phone 7 specific, it still has to do with updating the UI while waiting for a task to complete:

- [How To Load UI Independent Of Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578342/how-to-load-ui-independent-of-data)

Here's a Windows Phone 7 specific tutorial for using the `BackgroundWorker`:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/20/creating-progress-dialog-for-wp7.aspx

Comment: I tried this several times, with several different configurations, and always got some sort of error or other. When using some code from the MSDN page and your previous answer, I got a message saying "System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled" and "invalid cross thread access". Fortunately, I was able to use Thomas's answer above to salvage some sort of a loader. Thanks anyway; your answer opened my mind to the world of the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp: You were trying to update the UI in the background thread.  You need to use the `Dispatcher` class to post updates to your UI.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924408/invalid-cross-thread-access-issue

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp: The advantage of the `BackgroundWorker` over other options is if you have a long running task, and you want to support cancellation, it already has a built-in mechanism for it.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731610/cancel-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-task - you can see from that question that you have to "roll your own" for the cancellation if you use `QueueUserWorkItem`.  If your task isn't that long running, and you never want to cancel it, don't worry about it tho :)

Comment: Yeah, my task isn't that long-running, and I can't foresee any reason to cancel it.

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp: Then the other option is probably less code to implement.  Cheers!