# What is the advantage of creating a thread outside threadpool?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Okay, So I wanted to know what happens when I use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. By [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105988/taskcreationoptions-longrunning-option-and-threadpool) answer, I came to know that for long running tasks, I should use this options because it creates a thread **outside of threadpool**.

Cool. But what advantage would I get when I create a thread outside threadpool? And when to do it and avoid it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what advantage would I get when I create a thread outside threadpool?

The threadpool, as it name states, is a pool of threads which are allocated once and re-used throughout, in order to save the time and resources necessary to allocate a thread. The pool itself re-sizes on demand. If you queue more work than actual workers exist in the pool, it will allocate more threads in 500ms intervals, one at a time (this exists to avoid allocation of multiple threads simultaneously where existing threads may already finish executing and can serve requests). If many long running operations are performed on the thread-pool, it causes "thread starvation", meaning delegates will start getting queued and ran only once a thread frees up. That's why you'd want to avoid a large amount of threads doing lengthy work with thread-pool threads.

[The Managed Thread-Pool docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx) also have a section on this question:

> There are several scenarios in which it is appropriate to create and
>   manage your own threads instead of using thread pool threads:
>
> - You require a foreground thread.
> - You require a thread to have a particular priority.
> - You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of    time. The thread pool has a maximum number of threads, so a large
>     number of blocked thread pool threads might prevent tasks from
>     starting.
> - You need to place threads into a single-threaded apartment. All    ThreadPool threads are in the multithreaded apartment.
> - You need to have a stable identity associated with the thread, or to    dedicate a thread to a task.

For more, see:

- [Thread vs ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool)
- [When should I not use the ThreadPool in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274/when-should-i-not-use-the-threadpool-in-net)
- [Dedicated thread or thread-pool thread?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/08/05/dedicated-thread-or-a-threadpool-thread.aspx)

Comment: "The threadpool, as it name states, is a thread of pools." - Hahaha

Answer (score 4):

"Long running" can be quantified pretty well, a thread that takes more than half a second is running long.  That's a mountain of processor instructions on a modern machine, you'd have to burn a fat five billion of them per second.  Pretty hard to do in a constructive way unless you are calculating the value of Pi to thousands of decimals in the fraction.

Practical threads can only take that long when they are not burning core but are *waiting* a lot.  Invariably on an I/O completion, like reading data from a disk, a network, a dbase server.  And often the reason you'd start considering using a thread in the first place.

The threadpool has a "manager".  It determines when a threadpool thread is allowed to start.  It doesn't happen *immediately* when you start it in your program.  The manager tries to limit the number of running threads to the number of CPU cores you have.  It is much more efficient that way, context switching between too many active threads is expensive.  And a good throttle, preventing your program from consuming too many resources in a burst.

But the threadpool manager has the very common problem with managers, it doesn't know enough about what is going on.  Just like my manager doesn't know that I'm goofing off at Stackoverflow.com, the tp manager doesn't know that a thread is waiting for something and not *actually* performing useful work.  Without that knowledge it cannot make good decisions.  A thread that does a lot of waiting should be ignored and another one should be allowed to run in its place.  Actually doing real work.

Just like you tell your manager that you go on vacation, so he can expect no work to get done, you tell the threadpool manager the same thing with LongRunning.

Do note that it isn't quite a bad as it, perhaps, sounds in this answer.  Particularly .NET 4.0 hired a new manager that's a lot smarter at figuring out the optimum number of running threads.  It does so with a feedback loop, collecting data to discover if active threads actually get work done.  And adjusts the optimum accordingly.  Only problem with this approach is the common one when you close a feedback loop, you have to make it slow so the loop cannot become unstable.  In other words, it isn't particularly quick at driving up the number of active threads.

If you know ahead of time that the thread is pretty abysmal, running for *many* seconds with no real cpu load then always pick LongRunning.  Otherwise it is a tuning job, observing the program when it is done and tinkering with it to make it more optimal.